# Possible to make a site like urban dictionary using WP?

Tags: customization

Wordpress is great for blogs and has a ton of plugins and customization potential, so I'm wondering if it could also be used to make a site very similar in functionality and scope to Urban Dictionary? The main idea is to allow registered users to post short written entries, which anyone can then vote up or down.

Obviously this is a bit more complex than the average blog, if only because you would need a backend to contain user data. Ideally this site would attract a lot of traffic and could be monetized through online ads. Generating revenue is crucial as this is a business idea not a side hobby, so frameworks that don't allow for this are not acceptable. Is Wordpress well suited for this or are there better options?

Comment: This is possible, but is going to need plenty of work. The biggest issue that you are going to face is security. You will need to look at front end posting interface and restrict access to the back end. Also, you will need to deal with spammers and hackers. Google ads is another tough one when it comes to advertising. They have strick rules about content, so you will need to have full control and input on what users will post. A good "stopword" system should be implemented to stop illegal content. The choices are yours, and all I can say is, good luck on this project

Comment: @PieterGoosen so Wordpress doesn't provide any sort of built in security for multi-user sites? Surely there are plugins for this...?

Comment: It does, but you will need extra security. Never rely on the build in security